Comments for Generic Parameter
I need help with adding the  comments for the type of the return type of SomeMethod which is the Task of the Generic class SomeClass and the generic type T where T is SomeOtherClass.
I saw some reference to the following usage
<seealso cref="SomeClass{T}" />. 

However, I don't know how to add reference to where T is SomeOtherClass.
public class SomeClass<T>
    where T : SomeOtherClass
{

}

public class SomeOtherClass
{

}

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
   internal class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns></returns>
       /// <seealso cref="" />
       public async Task<SomeClass<SomeOtherClass>> SomeMethod()
       { 
    
       }
   }
}


Why do you need this? The documentation generator can't generate a link to SomeClass<SomeOtherClass> anyway, because there is only one documentation page for SomeClass, and that page is titled SomeClass<T>.

Document the type constraint separately. Then you can link to SomeOtherClass and make it clear that T in SomeClass{T} must 'is-a' SomeOtherClass.
